# main function stack size

Tags: c++

Max function stack size is limited and can be quickly exhausted if we use big stack variables or get careless with recursive functions.

But main's stack isn't really a stack. main is always called exactly once and never recursively. By all means main's stack is static storage allocated at the very beginning and it lives until the very end. Does it mean I can allocate big arrays in main's stack?

```
int main()
{
    double a[5000000];
}
```

Comment: It just uses an ordinary stack frame and is often near the very bottom of the stack.

Comment: Interesting thought, it could just as well be done in one of the initialized memory areas of the program mapping.  I'm pretty sure it doesn't work that way, but not 100% so I'll leave it up to brighter people :)

Comment: @WTP, calling `main()` is forbidden by the standard.  "The function `main` shall not be used within a program.", **§3.6.1 Main function**, paragraph 3.

Comment: @Carl Norum sorry, my bad. Is this also forbidden in C? I have seen this used.

Comment: ANSI C allows main to be called, if I remember correctly. But not C++.

Comment: I just did a quick spec check - @Macmade is correct for C99 from what I can see.

Comment: I can't think of any reason that a compiler couldn't perform this optimization, but I would be surprised if one did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's implementation-defined (the language standard doesn't talk about stacks, AFAIK).  But typically, `main` lives on the stack just like any other function.

Answer (score 3):

`main` is just a normal function. Stack size is system dependent.

Alos remember your process shares only one stack, for all function calls. Items are pushed and popped from the stack, as function are called by `main`.

Comment: `main` isn't really a *normal* function; there are all kinds of special requirements placed on it by the standard.

Comment: Nitpick: Different threads within the same process will each have their own stack space.

Answer (score 2):

It's 100% compiler and system dependent, like most of this kind of funny business.  Heck, even the *existence* of the stack isn't mandated by the standard.

In practice, yes, it's on the stack, and no, you can't allocate things like that on the stack without running into trouble.

Comment: Existence of a stack in the computer science sense is required by the standard. It is of utmost importance both in support for recursive function and in guaranteed execution of destructors. On all extant machines that abstract stack is mapped to a simple array-like machine stack (and that includes the silly machine where each process would see just a window in the registers). And if you design some new machine with less simple stack, it will still be a stack, just not simplest possible. And a C++ implementation will still use it, or use some other simpler stack. Hth.,

Comment: -1 silly incorrect statement "the existence of the stack isn't mandated by the standard"

Comment: I don't know, I can imagine at least theoretically an omniscient program that has hardcoded all possible outputs and inputs - it wouldn't require a stack.  Now whether a language implementation were to try to optimize that sort of corner case or not is another question.  I didn't really intend to suggest that a given implementation might not have a stack - it seems like a quite reasonable assumption to make.  I just meant to highlight the platform-specific nature of the question and any possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you allocate an array in that manner, it is allocated on the stack.  There is a platform-dependent maximum size the stack can grow to.  And yes, you've exceeded it.

Comment: "And yes, you've exceeded it." while you clearly say it is platform-dependent. O:

Comment: Well, he's getting a stack overflow bug or he wouldn't be asking, right?  So clearly he exceeded it.

Comment: Well, in this particular case, the solution may well be to increase the limit. It's usually artificial anyway.

Comment: No, the solution is to just allocate some memory already.  New exists for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Second thought, I just remembered - it can be called recursively.  Check out this obfuscated code:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code

It calls main many times and works wonders :) It's a fun link anyway.  So, its definitely stack allocated, sorry about that!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the standard disallows the calling of main in C++.  (If you can in reality may be a different matter altogether.)

Answer (score 0):

The stack is something that is used by all functions - the way you've worded your question suggests that each function is given a stack which is not the case.

Stack usage grows with each function call - `main()` being the first.  The allocation that you used in your example is just as bad as making a stack allocation in another function.

Answer (score 0):

For most modern systems, there is no real reason the stack size needs to be limited. You can probably adjust an operating system parameter and that program will work fine. (As will any that allocates an equal amount of data on the stack, `main` or not.)

However, if you really want an object with a lifetime equal to the duration of the program, create a global variable instead of a local inside `main`. Most platforms do not artificially limit the size of global objects — they can usually be as large as the memory map allows.

By the way, `main` is not active for the duration of a C++ program. It may be preceded by construction of global objects and followed by destruction of same and `atexit` handlers.